# Python | Как сделать скрипт который сам в себя мог добавлять кодд, не удаляя прежний

Tags: python, файлы, ос

а как можно сделать чтобы скрипт .py добавлял себе строки кода при этом не удаляя код, а перенося его ниже, к примеру:

```
есть строчка 219
я при помощи скрипта добавляю туда код, файл дополняет сам себя
при этом не удаляя, а данные находящиеся в этой строчке перенося ниже на определённое колличество строчек
```

Comment: В теории такое возможно, однако я лично не знаю как переность строчку

Comment: зачем вам это? даже на ассемблере это, скорее, развлечение.

Comment: это для создания конфигов, новых переменных, функций и так далее

Comment: а в моём случае упрощения роботы

Comment: Считываете все информацию из файла в переменную, изменяете в ней что хотите, перезаписываете файл с новыми данными. Так как программа уже была запущена, то удаление ни на что не повлияет. Способов не удалять файл не находил, когда сталкивался с подобной проблемой.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- читаете файл через `readlines`, получаете список строк
- выводите строки до нужной обратно в файл, используйте срез `[:n]`
- выводите в файл новые строки
- выводите в файл строки из среза `[n:]`

Comment: В принципе это правильно, но не могли бы вы подать пример в коде